# What is debug assertion? How to get words of a line into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

The following error occurs when trying to get the words of a line into an array. And I can see that "Word" represents the entire line instead of a single word. When I run the built exe file, it prints "Unable to open file" . Why is it happening?

Debug Assertion failed
Expression: string subscript out of range

```
void read_input_array(char* fileName,string*foo){

    string line2;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(fileName);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int k = 0;
        while (getline(myfile, line2)){

            for (int i = 0; i < line2.length();i++){
                string word = "";
                while (line2[i] != ',' || line2[i] != '.' || line2[i] != '\n'){
                    word = word + line2[i];
                    i++;
                }
                foo[k] = word;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    else { 
        cout << "Unable to open file\n"; 
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: as well as what the answers have; you don't need to check for `\n` because `getline` stops when it hit that already; and look into the `find_first_of` member function for `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition to the loop should be:

```
while (line2[i] != ',' && line2[i] != '.' && line2[i] != '\n')
```

Comment: Ok got it but I think there's something wrong with checking for '\n'.

Comment: @Zoey This is not quite right, see my answer which I have almost finished writing.

Comment: I modified the condition to this and it works fine now.     while (line2[i] != ',' && line2[i] != '.' && line2[i]!= ' ' && i<line2.length())

Comment: @Zoey Stick around for my long winded explanation of why you have to do that :)

Answer (score 3):

`string subscript out of range` indicates that you attempted to read a string's character either before index zero or after the last index. There are two lines where you accessed a character in a string, and therefore could have caused this:

```
           while (line2[i] != ',' || line2[i] != '.' || line2[i] != '\n'){
                word = word + line2[i];
```

Since `i` has the same value on these two lines, and `i` is never less than zero, you know that `i` has been set to a value beyond the end of the string. Here, the error occurs when you continue to increase `i` in the following line inside the `while` loop, without checking that the new value of `i` is not beyond your string size. Thus, if your while loop runs to the end of the string, it will try to test the character after the end of the string and cause an error. You must instead check that you do not go to far by starting your while loop with

```
while (i < line2.length() && ([rest of condition])) {
```

However, as 0x499602D2 pointed out, the condition for your while loop also has a logic error. In English, your condition states `while this character is not ',', or it is not '.', or it is not '\n'`. Note the very important repetition of `it is not`: Your condition has three `!=`s in it and therefore asks whether X is not Y three times: Your condition **does not read** `while this character is not ',', '.', or '\n'` Instead, your statement checks whether the character either is not one thing or is not the other thing, and since characters can't be two things at once your statement is always true. Instead, you must require that it is not one thing, *and* it is not the other thing, *and* it is not the third thing either: `line2[i] != ',' && line2[i] != '.' && line2[i] != '\n'`. In full:

```
while (i < line2.length() && line2[i] != ',' && line2[i] != '.' && line2[i] != '\n') {
```